# What is the maximum amount of an Elements asset that can be issued?

Tags: liquid, elements

Elements allow for assets issuance, and I was wondering what was the limit to the number of units that we can issue for each asset.

There's a limit to the amount that can be issued each time, which is 21 millions, but it seems that by issuing 21 millions again and again I can issue much more than that.

My guess is that the max amount that could be issued is the maximum number of satoshis that can fit in a `int64_t`, which should be `92,233,720,368.54775807`, am I getting this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no maximum that can be created, however you may run into issues with RPC-APIs in Elements if any wallet contains more than 92,233,720,368.54775807 at any time.

Confidential transactions will function with any realistic amount (you would have to re-issue an asset more times than possible to overload the 256-bit confidential amount type, however the receivers wallet would fail if int64 overflows.

Comment: If I remember correctly, confidential transactions do have a limit of its own though, but it is not a problem since it is impossible to make a transaction with an output bigger than 21 millions. Each issuance being a transaction itself limited to 21 millions, there's indeed no problem doing confidential asset issuances